# QR code from base64 encoded string Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, base64, qr-code, angular2-template

I have variable with base64 encoded string and I would like to decode it and after that, displayed it in a HTML template. I am using Angular 2 with typescript.

So I am looking for some base64 encode/decode library for Angular2/Typescript and some options to create an image from decoded string.

Thanks

Comment: So sorry, I mixed it up with Dart because I was working on Dart questions previously.

Comment: to `encode/decode` in base64 javascript's `btoa()/atob()` methods would be enough, to generate a QR code `angular` had [this](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) third party component but [support for `angular2` still seems under consideration](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode/issues/39)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with something like this:

```
this.QRCode = "data:image/png;base64," + base64EncodedQRCodeInString;
```

`this.QRCode` is mapped to template by property binding, for example `<img [src]="QRCode" />`, it is not neccessary to decode it from base64. The browsers have the full support for base64 encoded strings.

Comment: How are you creating your base64EncodedQRCodeInString ?
And what is "this" in your code here ?

Comment: base64EncodedQRCodeInString is from JAVA backend REST API, it was created by:  

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
stream = QRCode
        .from(generatedQRInput + delimeter + signWithKeyId.getId() + ";" + Base64Utils.encodeToString(signWithKeyId.getSign()))
        .withCharset("UTF-8")
        .stream();

if (stream != null) {
    return Base64Utils.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray());
}